# Spacy get pos & tag for specific word

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, tagging, part-of-speech

I came across a situation where i have to get the pos_ & tag_ from spacy doc objects.

For example,

```
text = "Australian striker John hits century"
doc = nlp(text)
for nc in doc.noun_chunks:
    print(nc) #Australian striker John
doc[1].tag_ # gives for striker
```

if I want to get `pos_` & `tag_` for word 'striker' do I need to again give that sentence to `nlp()` ??

Also doc[1].tag_ is there, but I need something like doc['striker'].tag_ ..

Is there any possibility ?

Comment: Well, firstly something like `doc['striker'].tag_` would be ambiguous if there are multiple "striker" words within the sentence. But in regards to your original question, what do you mean `do I need to again give that sentence`? Already you have `doc[1].tag_ == 'NN'` and `doc[1].pos_ == 'NOUN'`.

Comment: "do I need to again give that sentence to `nlp()`?" Yes because POS tags depend on the context. For example "hits" without the context could be a noun (plural of "hit") or a verb. You could probably map each token to their position and do something like `doc[index[word]]` but that causes problems if the same word appears multiple times.

Comment: Okay. I don't think you'd need to parse a sentence more than once. when `doc` is ready, all the positions are already correctly calculated based on context as you say. You can do `print([token.pos_ for token in doc])` it returns `['ADJ', 'NOUN', 'PROPN', 'VERB', 'NOUN']`.

Comment: @darksky but how to get the tags only the the detected noun chunks.. Like if big paragraph is there.?

Comment: @VivekAnanthan A noun chunk is a `spacy.tokens.span.Span` not a token. You have to iterate it to print the tag of each token inside a chunk, like so `print([[token.tag_ for token in nc] for nc in doc.noun_chunks])`

Answer (score 2):

You only have to process the text once:

```
text = "Australian striker John hits century"
doc = nlp(text)
for nc in doc.noun_chunks:
    print(nc)  
    print([(token.text, token.tag_, token.pos_) for token in nc])
```

If you only want to get a specific word within the noun chunk, you can further filter this by changing the second print statement to e.g.

```
print([(token.text, token.tag_, token.pos_) for token in nc if token.tag_ == 'NN'])
```

Note that this may print multiple hits, depending on your model & input sentence.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
text = "Australian striker John hits century"
x1 = "striker"
x2 = re.compile(x1,re.IGNORECASE | re.VERBOSE)
loc_indexes = [m.start(0) for m in re.finditer(x2, text )]
tag = [i.tag_ for i in nlp(text) if i.idx in loc_indexes ]
print(x1,tag[0])
```

it gives output:
`striker NN`

You can also easily make it dynamic if required with x1 being the variable.